# Received Contact via WhatsApp is stored in Phone - How to move it to Google without losing the image

Tags: contacts, google-account, whatsapp-messenger

For some time now I'm experiencing the following issue: When someone sends me a contact via WhatsApp it is stored in my phone and not my Google address book.

How can I move this thing to Google or configure WhatsApp to save it to Google? When I use the *.vcf export I get mail and phone number but the image is lost somewhere in Nirvana...

Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what phone you have, you can try to hit the edit button on the contact, then tap phone contact, and choose the google account. In my test, it saved the picture.

-Adam

Comment: Well, didn't work on my Samsung S2... Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in lot of ways the easiest way is to export your contacts to storage and import vcard file from contacts.google.com
another one is if you need one or two contact then note down phone number and delete the contact and create a new contact save it in google
hope this will help..